# Set Focus for a specific duration

Tags: macos, settings, do-not-disturb, control-center, focus

By default, the 'Focus' button in the control center of macOS provides three options. Among them, there is a 'For 1 hour'.
I would like to have a similar 'Focus' with its duration configurable, such as 2 hours or so.
But looking into the settings, it seems that one can only 'schedule' a Focus like from 13:00 to 14:30. This is rather different from the duration-only thing.

How to do this?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JBallin A Focus with a specified duration but without a start time. So I can start it at any time like the default 'For 1 hour' thing.

Comment: Not sure there's a way to do this, those options are part of the service. Maybe you could just set a schedule for a focus?

Comment: Can you provide a specific use case?

Comment: @JBallin A Focus 'For 2 hours' in which one does not need to specify start/end time.

Comment: Your question is "how do I solve my problem by implementing this specific solution?" - what "problem" are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Shortcuts.app can change the Focus based on a custom time.

Here are the macOS Shortcut.app actions:

1. **Date**
   //gets the current date
2. **Adjust Date** - [add] [#] to [Date]
   //adds time to the current date
3. **Set Variable** - ["Time"] to [Adjusted Date]
   //creates a variable called "Time" with the time the Focus will change
4. **Set Focus** - [Turn] [Do Not Disturb] on until [Time] [(Select the Variable "Time")]
   //The Do Not Disturb focus will turn on until the adjusted date.

[image: Screenshot of macOS Shortcuts.app with the four actions]

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this isn't an option, however there is a built in app called "Shortcuts" that you can use!

Open the app and take a look at the starter shortcut called "Take a break". When you use it you can set your shortcut to a set amount of minutes, and it puts you into the "do not disturb" focus. Just duplicate this, and edit the shortcut so the "do not disturb" focus is instead your work focus.

Thanks for your post by the way, as I really wanted this functionality too. I think this is as close as we will get until a new update comes along. The fact that this is a starter shortcut from Apple shows that we will possibly get this soon.